# Find a private interface field with Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, webforms

Given this class

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    private IRepository repo;
    ...
}
```

I want to find and set the private `repo` field. Is that possible?

### UPDATE

I tried using the `GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic)`, it returns `{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}`.

### UPDATE II

I tried using the `GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)`
, it returns all the fields of the `Page` but not `repo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx) overload that allows you to specify flags:

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding BindingFlags.Instance. If you specify no flags you get (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance), but if you specify any you get only the ones you specify, so you need either Instance or Static to get any results.

Comment: Don't forget that it will only return the fields for the current type, you may have to walk down the hierarchy if the field is defined in a base class.

Comment: Jb Evain: When I change 'repo' to public it does work, just when I change it to private it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code :

MemberInfo[] mi = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(MyType);

and convert FieldInfo fi = (FieldInfo) mi[i];
this code return Serializable Members (privates)

Comment: For using your solution my page needs to be Serializable, is this the only way??

Comment: yes, 
I think there are another way, it's using debugging service like Quick Watch in Visual Studio, but you need the .pdb files